# Burninate implicit-cast and re-tag to implicit-conversion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The tag [implicit-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-cast) doesn't make sense in most programming languages - the tag name itself is a misconception. As correctly stated in the tag wiki:

> In C and C++, there is no such thing as an implicit cast. There are implicit and explicit *conversions*; a cast is explicit by definition. Consider using the "implicit-conversion" tag instead. (Other languages might define the word "cast" differently.)

Unless there's some strange language using a different meaning for the term "cast", we should be able to replace this tag with [implicit-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-conversion) in all the 96 posts using it.

Comment: Apparently, [someone tried to invent it in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496874/why-uses-implicit-castsize-tint-instead-of-static-castsize-tint), though...

Comment: @CodyGray C++ turns worse every single day... but it appears to something barfed out by boost? In that case maybe questions about the boost thing should be named [tag:boost-implicit-cast] or such.

Comment: Although... "implicit cast" is implemented as an explicit cast `implicit_cast<type>`. It all seems to be one big brain fart.

Comment: Yeah, [it's a Boost thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868306/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-implicit-cast). It's certainly convoluted. I imagine that is why the tag got created, though, and has been misused ever since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proposal:

- Review all posts tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [implicit-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-cast) to see if one of them is about the strange boost feature `implicit_cast`. If such a post exists, re-tag to a new tag [boost-implicit-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-implicit-cast) and add the [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost) tag to such posts as well.

  **EDIT : done.** I found 2 posts out of 25, they have been re-tagged with the new [boost-implicit-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-implicit-cast) tag.
- For all remaining posts, change [implicit-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-cast) to [implicit-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-conversion). We may need moderator assistance with this so we don't disrupt the site needlessly by bumping the 96 posts.

  **EDIT : done.** A friendly mod has fixed the remaining posts.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the edit. *I'm* the mod who fixed the remaining posts. :-)